# Base pointer offset adjustment for multiple inheritance question

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I know base offset adjustment will happen in this situation

```
class Mother {
 public:
  virtual void MotherMethod() {}
  int mother_data;
};

class Father {
 public:
  virtual void FatherMethod() {}
  int father_data;
};

class Child : public Mother, public Father {
 public:
  virtual void ChildMethod() {}
  int child_data;
};
```

```
Father *f = new Child;
```

During compilation, this code is equivalent to

```
Child *tmp = new Child;
Father *f = tmp ? tmp + sizeof(Mother) : 0;
```

---

My question is how this offset is determined in the compilation phase？
for example, in the following case

```
void fun(Father* f) {
    // do something
}
```

we don't know what object the pointer will receive, how is it possible to determine whether or how much offset adjustment is needed during compilation.

I hope someone can answer my doubts， Thank you very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680369/how-is-inheritance-implemented-at-the-memory-level https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467884/how-does-c-compiler-handle-member-variable-memory-offset-in-the-case-of-multip https://medium.com/geekculture/c-inheritance-memory-model-eac9eb9c56b5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caller of a function knows exactly what types are involved and does the necessary adjustments.

That is,

```
Child c;
fun(&c);
```

behaves exactly the same as

```
Child c;
fun(static_cast<Father*>(&c));
```

but the conversion is implicit.